# Create Daily Task to run a command

Tags: cron, jobs

How can I create a daily task to run a command which outputs the results into a file that gets emailed?

I would like to run the following command:

```
find ./ -type f -size 510c -name "*.php" -mtime -3
```

in the following location:

```
/var/www/vhosts/
```

I would like to add this a cron job so I get the contents emailed ONLY if the file is not empty.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible write a one-liner to do this, but if not, you can write a script.  Below is a perl script that should do the job:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my($cmd, $r);
my($to, $from, $subject, $message);

$cmd="find /var/www/vhosts/ -type f -size 510c -name \"*.php\" -mtime -3";
$r=`$cmd`;

if(length($r)>0) {
  $to = 'to@to.com';
  $from = 'from@from.com';
  $subject = 'This is the subject';
  $message = $r;

  open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");

  # Email Header
  print MAIL "To: $to\n";
  print MAIL "From: $from\n";
  print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
  # Email Body
  print MAIL $message;

  close(MAIL);
}
```

Just save this to a file (e.g. script.pl), then just add a line to your crontab like so:

```
x x x x x perl /path/to/script.pl
```